# Bootstrap 3 Fixed Top Navbar - style bottom edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Was playing with an idea for a site and wondered how I would add a transparent png with an irregular shape along the bottom edge of the navbar that hangs over the body of the page.

I've seen some tutorials and answers on placing an oversized logo but wondered it if were possible to have the image repeat itself all the way across, pinned to the bottom edge of the bar.

Not sure how to proceed...

Just for something to play with, here is a png of grass with transparent background.

[image: Spring Grass]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried, Kyle!

Comment: According to the "types of questions that can be asked" page, my question fits the criteria. 

"but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem"

Answer (score 1):

If you must, using a pseudo-element would seem to be optimal

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.navbar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EhS4.png);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I made a JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/njf1kzzm/2/). I could explain everything that I did here but the fiddle has a lot of comments that explain everything. What it does is set the position of the image `absolute`, the `width` is 100% and the `top` margin is equal to the height of the navbar.

Hope this helps you with your problem :)

Comment: Got those comments backwards. lol This makes perfect sense and works like I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Just curious but do you find this question to not adhere to guidelines?